# Markdown is giving me a distorted table despite the output showing a pretty one

Tags: r, knitr

I used the Arsenal package to run my descriptive analysis. The output shows both the console and knit_asis, which shows a pretty table. However, when I knit my work into a .word document, I get a very distorted table. Apparently I have to create a chunk using the "asis" functionality, but I am struggling on how to write such a code. Help, please!

Below are the screenshots of the R output and what I get in the word document.

[image: Word]

[image: R OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a table of your summary, then print using kable():

```r
tab_to_print <- summary(table_discriptive, labelTranslations = my_labels, title = "Characteristics of 598 Study Participants Stratified by HIV Status")

kable(tab_to_print)
```

If you use that code and knit to Word, it will print the pretty table you see in the output.